# How can I get one circle for every three months

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using this link to learn D3.Js
I want to draw circles, but I want a circle for every three months
I tried to create a new data sub of the original data, but this didn't work
https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/area_lineDot.html

```js
temp =[]
for (i=0; i< data.length; i=i+3) {
    temp.push(data[i]);
}
```

I need to modify this code

```js
svg.selectAll("myCircles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value) })
    .attr("r", 3)
```

Comment: With the code that you have written already, what is it rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
svg.selectAll("myCircles")
    .data(temp)   // <---------- Use 'temp' instead of 'data'
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value) })
    .attr("r", 3)
```

Comment: Thank you Simon yes this worked the issue was the way Im reading the d.date and d.value

Answer (score 0):

I got this working now the issue was the way I was reading the d.date and d.value the data has string need to be change to int
thank you Simon

Comment: would you be able to provide the code that fixed it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).